# Python - slicing on the z-plane

Tags: python, matplotlib, multidimensional-array, imshow

I have a 3d list of lists `mylist`, whose shape is

```
(30, 30, 580)
```

I would like to slice it on a `z`-plane, say for example at `z=100`.

I have tried the following

```
plt.imshow(mylist[:][:][100],origin='lower', aspect='auto')
plt.show()
```

which produces the error

```
index 100 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 30
```

As far as I understand, it seems as though `imshow` is able to deal only with the `x` and `y` plane, but cannot slice on the `z` plane. How to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `mylist` is a list of lists of lists, you could slice along the third axis by using

```
[[mylist[i][j][100] for j in range(30)] for i in range(30)]
```

However, since you are using matplotlib, you must also have NumPy installed. So
it would be easier to convert `mylist` into a NumPy array and then use NumPy indexing:

```
myarrary = np.array(mylist)
plt.imshow(myarray[..., 100], origin='lower', aspect='auto')
```

---

The reason why `mylist[:][:][100]` does not work is because `mylist[:]` returns a shallow copy of `mylist` -- a new list with the exact same contents as `mylist`. So both `mylist` and `mylist[:][:]` are lists of lists of lists.

`mylist[:][:][100]` fails for the same reason that `mylist[100]` would fail -- the top level contents of `mylist` only has 30 items.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `mylist` is a numpy array, try `mylist[:, :, 100]`.